# how to set origin in opengl for 3d objects

Tags: c++, opengl, isometric

I am trying to draw the cube as vertices and window position is set,but i am not getting right cube. I am getting the cube at right top side and dimensions are not as I gave. I am new to opengl. please help.

```
#include <gl/glut.h> 
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#ifdef __APPLE__
#else
#endif


void display();
void specialKeys();


double rotate_y=0; 
double rotate_x=0;


void display(){

//  Clear screen and Z-buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Reset transformations
glLoadIdentity();

 // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
  glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
  glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );



  // side - FRONT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

  glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );  
  glVertex3f(  0, 0, 0);      
  glVertex3f( 40,0,0);      
  glVertex3f(40,40,0  );     
  glVertex3f(0,40,0 );      

  glEnd();

  //  side - BACK
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   1.0,0.0,1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0,0,40 );
  glVertex3f(  0,40,40);
  glVertex3f( 40,40,40 );
  glVertex3f( 40,0,40 );
  glEnd();

  //  side - RIGHT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,0,0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,0,40 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,40 );
  glEnd();

  //  side - LEFT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,40,0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,40,40 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,40 );
  glEnd();

  //  side - TOP
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  0.0,0.0,1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0,40,0);
  glVertex3f( 0,40,40 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,40 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,0 );
  glEnd();

  //  side - BOTTOM
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  1.0,  0.5,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,0 );
  glVertex3f(  40,0,0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,0,40 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,40);
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();

}
 void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluOrtho2D(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
    glOrtho(0,      // left
        1000,  // right
        0, // bottom
        1000,      // top
        0,      // zNear
        1000       // zFar
        );
}

void specialKeys( int key, int x, int y ) {

  //  Right arrow - increase rotation by 5 degree
  if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    rotate_y += 5;

  //  Left arrow - decrease rotation by 5 degree
  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    rotate_y -= 5;

  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    rotate_x += 5;

  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    rotate_x -= 5;

  //  Request display update
  glutPostRedisplay();

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
  glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
  // Create window
  glutCreateWindow("Awesome Cube");

  //  Enable Z-buffer depth test
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);
  init();
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is because since you didn't specify your camera Position and LookAt Position. So opengl Assume you are looking to Origin (0,0,0).  So it is normal that your cube will appear top right on the screen.

if you want to see it in the center you can apply translatef function before rotation calls :

```
glTranslatef(-20.0f,-20.0f,-20.0f); //Shift your object to the center
glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
                     ...
```

Comment: i want to set my origin at top left corner. and my glortho function is                      glOrtho(0,      // left
        1000,  // right
        0, // bottom
        1000,      // top
        0,      // zNear
        1000       // zFar
        );                                   so i want a cube having side 40,so it should be at top left corner and dimensions should be as i gave. what is the error in the code. plz help.